# Plain authentication failed: User yarn is not configured for any impersonation. impersonationUser: root in alluxio mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, alluxio

Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Plain authentication failed: User yarn is not configured for any impersonation. impersonationUser: root

It works fine when I run wordcount program locally with alluxio . I also passed the integration test but when I run the same Hadoop program with alluxio client jar
it gives me an error

```
bin/hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount -libjars /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/alluxio-1.8.1-client.jar alluxio://172.17.0.2:19998/wordcount/input.txt alluxio://172.17.0.2:19998/wordcount/output
```

> Error: alluxio.exception.status.UnavailableException: Failed to connect to FileSystemMasterClient @ quickstart.cloudera/172.17.0.2:19998 after 44 attempts

Answer (score 1):

Solved alluxio also needs an impersonation in `alluxio-site.properties` set

```
alluxio.master.security.impersonation.root.users=*
alluxio.master.security.impersonation.root.groups=*
alluxio.master.security.impersonation.client.users=*
alluxio.master.security.impersonation.client.groups=*
alluxio.security.login.impersonation.username=none
```