# Alluxio + Hive on EMR

Tags: hive, amazon-emr, alluxio

I have Alluxio 1.8 installed on an EMR 5.19.0 cluster, and can see my S3 tables using `/usr/local/alluxio/bin/alluxio fs ls /`.

However, when I start up hive and issue
`hive> [[DDL w/ LOCATION = alluxio://master_host:19998/my_table ]]]`, I get the following:

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class alluxio.hadoop.FileSystem not found`

Is there a way of getting past this?  I've tried starting hive with `--auxpath` pointing to both `/usr/local/alluxio/client/alluxio-1.8.1-client.jar` and a copy of the jar on hdfs without any success.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a [blog](https://www.alluxio.com/blog/developer-tip-why-did-my-job-fail-with-error-message-class-alluxiohadoopfilesystem-not-found) talking about the reasons for the error message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class alluxio.hadoop.FileSystem not found`. Here are some tips, hope they can help:

- For Hive, set environment variable `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` in `conf/hive-env.sh`:

```bash
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/<PATH_TO_ALLUXIO>/client/alluxio-1.8.1-client.jar:${HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH}
```

which I guess is equivalent to what you have done to set `--auxpath`.

- Depending on your setting of Hive (e.g., Hive on MR or Spark or Tez), you may also need to make sure the runtime is also able to access the client jar. Take Hive on MR as an example, you perhaps also need to append the path to Alluxio client jar to `mapreduce.application.classpath` or `yarn.application.classpath` to ensure each task of the MR jobs can access this jar.

Comment: I'm able make progress by setting `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` to `/usr/local/alluxio/client/alluxio-1.8.1-client.jar` by configuring hive-env in the EMR configuration.

I'm still not able to create the temporary table though, I'm getting 
`
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: alluxio.exception.status.UnavailableException Failed to connect to FileSystemMasterClient @ <hostname/mask>:19998 after 44 attempts)
`

Comment: @rongenre, can you check if the solution of this issue helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810985/plain-authentication-failed-user-yarn-is-not-configured-for-any-impersonation

Comment: Impersonation took care of part of it, but I'm running into further downstream problems.  Will update when I get a resolution.